# Azure Function CLI irregular trigger timing and wrong details

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cli, azure-functions-runtime

I m testing Azure function locally using cli.

I have noticed 2 issues:

1. Sometimes CLI do not shows correct time when function will be executing. For example I have cron to execute function every two mins but it shows function will be executed after a difference of seconds ? weird.
2. Often it do not starts execution as per time shown in CLI, few times it took much time and then respond.

Is is normal ? Please guide how I can fix these.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`* */2 * * * *` cron expression means that you want to execute it every second (the first `*`) of every 2nd minute, so

```
2:50:00
2:50:01
2:50:02
...
2:50:59
2:52:00
2:52:01
etc
```

The correct expression is `0 */2 * * * *`: execute every 2nd minute when seconds are 0, which should give

```
2:50:00
2:52:00
```

Please check if you still have delays after this change, and it so, post it as a new question with exact description of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try `[TimerTrigger("0 */2 * * * *")]` see examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer)